# Ideapad 100-14 screen shows white lines then turns white/negative

Tags: windows, display, hardware-failure, lenovo-laptop

I bought a Lenovo Ideapad 100-14 just five months ago (it's running Windows). 
I have a problem with my screen that started just last week. 
Whenever I use it, the screen begins to show these white horizontal lines:

[image: photograph of screen]

The white lines appear from the bottom but now it just starts everywhere then turns negative /kind of white. It goes away when I move the monitor back and forth, but then it happens again after a few seconds or sometimes a few minutes.

Comment: Could you include any more details? A picture would be very helpful, I'm not quite sure what's going on at the moment. You should [edit] your post to add all relevant information.

Answer (score 1):

It's likely CPU/GPU/NB chip dead. Requires repair by chip replacement via soldering. In this model integrated video is on-chip with north bridge and CPU.

It can be a LCD matrix or a cable from the motherboard as well. This can be verified easily: connect external display - if the picture is fine on the external display then the issue is with the display.

Comment: are you familiar with the fact that on Intel Bay Trail platform North Bridge, CPU and GPU are on the same chip?
Also, he says that the issue disappears when he moves the screen - probably indicating some sort of issue with cabling.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't precise when wrote that GPU is integrated into the NB chip, but yes, CPU is the same chip. And yes, we had an experience to replace/resolder/reball chips like FH8065301729501 (It's Celeron on the same core). And I can assert that we had cases when reballing on these chips helped due to they exfoliated from the PCB surface due to some reasons.

Comment: shady soldering business on manufacturers side I guess :D
It sounds really odd that 10 watt chip loses connection with PCB.
btw, great suggestion in the most recent edit

Answer (score 1):

This is just a shot in the dark: I think you have some sort of issue with cables - perhaps even issue inside LCD panel itself.

**If your laptop is still in guarantee period, simply send it to service.**

If not and you are handy enough, try (**with caution**):

1. disassembling the laptop
2. unplugging LCD cable from motherboard and LCD panel itself and plugging it back in
3. try **gently** wiggling LCD and cable to check if you still have issues before putting everything back

I don't think it's an issue with unsoldered iGPU (entire SoC in this case) - *c'mon, Bay Trail chips use less than 10 watts total, no way that the chip got too hot to desolder itself*.

Comment: That doesn't look like a problem with the panel, itself, but my guess is that you're right about a bad connection, especially since the problem changes when the lid is moved.

Comment: too bad that the question was asked almost a month ago, god knows what happened to the guy that asked and the panel itself :D